# strtoul of negative number

Tags: c++, c, string

The following C++ program calls `strtoul` of negative 1.  Since no negative numbers are representable in any unsigned type, I had expected this to fail and return 0

> [If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/)

but instead a large positive number is returned

> [If the value read is out of the range of representable values by an unsigned long int, the function returns `ULONG_MAX` (defined in `<climits>`), and `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  {char s[] = "-1";
    for (int b=0; b<17; ++b)
      std::cout << "strtoul (unsigned) of " << s
                << " with base arg " << b
                << ": " << strtoul(s,0,b) << std::endl;}
}
```

Why does strtoul not fail and return 0 for negative numbers?

Comment: What's your OS?  Compiler?  C/C++ runtime?

Comment: @AndrewHenle. Irrelavant in this case. The function demonstrates correct behavior.

Comment: @Galik. Not true. It only **returns** unsigned numbers.

Comment: @MadPhysicist *The function demonstrates correct behavior.*  That would depend on the value of the "large positive number" returned.

Comment: @MadPhysicist right you are :)

Comment: @AndrewHenle. Technically true. I meant that in the sense that the OP has not described any unexpected behavior. If he listed a specific number that was not a power of 2 minus 1 for example, I would be more surprised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You better use cppreference.com for [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) it seems to be much more accurate:

> if the minus sign was part of the input sequence, the numeric value
>   calculated from the sequence of digits is negated as if by unary minus
>   in the result type, which applies unsigned integer wraparound rules.

and as mentioned there optional plus or minus sign is a valid symbol

Comment: What's inaccurate about the cplusplus.com documentation?

Comment: At least it is not as complete as this one, which means it is not accurate

Comment: @BenjaminLindley. The fact that they spelled out `++` instead of using the clearly more understandable truncation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yea it is very funny especially that you conclusions based on that site are incorrect (at least for gcc)

Comment: @Slava. Just out of curiosity, what version of the C++ standard are you using. I think that may be more relevant than the compiler.

Comment: I am using reference mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Slava. Fair enough. I checked it out, deleted my blatantly wrong answer. The references don't actually conflict, but cppreference does explain what overflow means in much more detail. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

[Per the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoul.html):

> Since `0`, `{ULONG_MAX}`, and `{ULLONG_MAX}` are returned on error and
>   are also valid returns on success, an application wishing to check for
>   error situations should set `errno` to `0`, then call `strtoul()` or
>   `strtoull()`, then check `errno`.

You need to check `errno`.

Comment: errno is 0 at least for RH 6.6 and gcc 5.1.0

Comment: @Slava `-1` would not be "outside the range of representable values".

Comment: [*grubles*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-of-Integers.html) "strtoul sets errno to EINVAL if base is out of range, or ERANGE on overflow.". Do programmers generally want "-1" to mean ULONG_MAX? that doesn't seem OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

From a different reference:  cppreference.com:

> Return value
>
> Integer value corresponding to the contents of str on success. If the
>   converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, range
>   error occurs and ULONG_MAX or ULLONG_MAX is returned. If no conversion
>   can be performed, ​0​ is returned.

Which is apparently different than cplusplus.com